# Would my Java web application be vulnerable if I use a netty version that is vulnerable to CVE-2019-20444 and CVE-2019-20445?

Tags: web-application, java, secure-coding

These has been fixed in later versions of Netty ... but what is the risk of using an older (can't upgrade now) version that is vulnerable to to CVE-2019-20444 and CVE-2019-20445 ... is there really a risk here? 
Note that the application uses netty for communicating with a 3rd party API. The app is deployed on Tomcat and that is the main entry for user http requests.

Comment: From a quick look these are HTTP request smuggling related, so would only matter when deployed behind a proxy. Double check this though - safest option is to deploy an unaffected version